# Customer Activation In Magento2

Tags: magento2

I have created Attribute of customer Activation with Boolean 1 and 0 value i want that if customer active attribute value 0 so customer cant login this is my observer code in magento 2

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
$customer_ativation=$customer->getCustomerActive(); //Get customer name
if($customer_ativation==1)
{

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/amitshree/magento2-account-approval

Comment: @boomer it gives me Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Plugin class Amitshree\Customer\Plugin\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost doesn't exist when logged in. How to approve the customer via admin panel

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$customer->setCustomAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_CODE, VALUE);` to set the value and `$customer->getCustomAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_CODE)->getValue();` to retrieve the value for custom customer attribute.

Comment: This should be also useful for you https://www.extensionhut.com/customer-approve-disapprove-for-magento-2.html